# Trying to create a Simple Filter App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to create a simple filter using Google Sheets App Script. That if cell C2 values contains `RAM' then Col"2" should hide all rows except 'RAM'. But its not working.

I have created a data validation in cell C2 which changes the value. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 function create_filter(){
        const  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Filter_Sheet");
        const  range = sheet1.getRange("A5:T");
        const  filter = range.createFilter();
    
        const Filter_Criteria1 = Sheet1.range('C2').getActiveCell;
        const coll1 = 2
        
        const  add_filter =  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(coll1,Filter_Criteria1);
    }
```

another try:

```
function create_filter(){
        const  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Filter_Sheet");
        const  range = sheet1.getRange("A4:T");
        const  filter = range.createFilter();
        var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D2');
        var range3 sheet1.getRange('C2').activate();
 
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .setHiddenValues([cell != range2 ])
  .build();
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(3, criteria);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create the basic filter that when a text of `RAM` is contained to the cell value, you want to show the rows.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function create_filter() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Filter_Sheet");
  const range = sheet1.getRange("A5:T");
  const filter = range.createFilter();
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(2, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains("RAM").build());
}
```

- In your 2 scripts, 2 ranges of `const range = sheet1.getRange("A5:T")` and `const  range = sheet1.getRange("A4:T")` are used. In this modification, `const range = sheet1.getRange("A5:T")` is used. About this, please modify it for your actual situation.
- When this script is run, the rows that `RAM` is contained at the value of column "B" are shown.

#### References:

- [setColumnFilterCriteria(columnPosition, filterCriteria)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#setcolumnfiltercriteriacolumnposition,-filtercriteria)
- [Class FilterCriteriaBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder)

### Added 1:

From the following replying in the comment and your script,

> I have created a data validation in cell C2 there are 10 to 11 different string in that validation including RAM. So i want to create a on edit function that whenever Cell C2 string changes script should RUN and Column B will show exact value that is available in cell C2

I thought that the sheet name is "Filter_Sheet" and the data validation is put to the cell "C2". But, when I saw your Spreadsheet, the sheet name is "Sheet1" and the data validation is put to the cell "C1". So the following sample script uses your sample Spreadsheet. When you change the sheet name, please modify `Sheet1` to others.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const offset = 0; // When the data validation is cell "C1" and "C2", please use 0 and 1, respectively.
  const {range, value} = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1" || range.getA1Notation() != "C" + (1 + offset)) return;
  const r = sheet.getRange(`A${4 + offset}:T`);
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter) {
    filter.remove();
  }
  r.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(value).build());
}
```

- From your following replying,

  > exactly the details are different because it is just sample sheet i can modify the code later when apply to real sheet

  - Please modify above script for your actual situation.

### Added 2:

From your following replying,

> but i am unable to edit this code. It is difficult for me to understand it, const value = sheet1.getRange('C2').getValue(); if this can be used then i can change the cell reference.

You want to run the script when the cell "C1" is edited. From your additional question, I understood like this. So, I proposed the modified script for using the event object of OnEdit simple trigger. But, when you don't want to use the event object, how about the following script?

```js
function onEdit() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const value = sheet1.getRange('C1').getValue();
  const range = sheet1.getRange("A4:T");
  const filter = sheet1.getFilter();
  if (filter) {
    filter.remove();
  }
  range.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(value).build());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for understanding this. The thing i am struggling to get is to use the cell reference instead of single value in d\script. That whenever cell value will changed script will run and the rows contained that value will be shown in Column B

Comment: @ShRa Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Your question is that you want to create the basic filter that when a text of RAM is contained to the cell value, you want to show the rows. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is not correct, I have to apologize for this. At first, can I ask you whether my understanding of your question is correct?

Comment: Sir actually you are right my skills in english are poor. I could not elaborate my question. But i mentioned in last there is a data validation in that cell but could not create a sense what i want. I apologize for it.

Comment: @ShRa Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. From your replying, I'm worried whether my understanding of your question might not be correct. So, can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By this, I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: Sir i appreciate you response and apologize for my poor English again. I have created a data validation in cell `C2` there are 10 to 11 different string in that validation including `RAM`. So i want to create a on edit function that whenever Cell `C2` string changes script should RUN and Column B will show exact value that is available in cell `C2`

Comment: @ShRa Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. From your replying, when I saw your question for the first time, I couldn't understand your replying from your question. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand `I have created a data validation in cell C2 there are 10 to 11 different string in that validation including RAM`, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @ShRa By the way, can I ask you about the relationship between `RAM` and your data validation in the cell "C2"?

Comment: Sir here is the attached sheet I have created an example sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15i1Ep46IUYLCl7odLy0YqHVJ00Z5qG_Urtwg_n5GOd4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sir i just take the unique values from Column B and added a filter from those values in cell C2.

Comment: @ShRa Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, the sheet name is "Sheet1" and the data validation is put to the cell "C1". So I'm confusing your question of `I have created a data validation in cell C2 there are 10 to 11 different string in that validation including RAM. So i want to create a on edit function that whenever Cell C2 string changes script should RUN and Column B will show exact value that is available in cell C2`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Sir exactly the details are different because it is just sample sheet i can modify the code later when apply to real sheet

Comment: @ShRa Thank you for replying. From your replying, I added one more sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize again.

Comment: Sir thank you very much for this favor but i am unable to edit this code. It is difficult for me to understand it, `const value = sheet1.getRange('C2').getValue();` if this can be used then i can change the cell reference.

Comment: @ShRa Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I cannot understand `i am unable to edit this code. It is difficult for me to understand it, const value = sheet1.getRange('C2').getValue(); if this can be used then i can change the cell reference.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? By this, I would like to try to understand it. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @ShRa I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. From `but i am unable to edit this code. It is difficult for me to understand it, const value = sheet1.getRange('C2').getValue(); if this can be used then i can change the cell reference.`, I added one more script without using the event object. Could you please confirm it? If that was also not useful, I apologize again.  This is for your sample Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.