# How to Create Further Filters using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to filtering the columns using Google Apps Script but i am unable to get that how the filter will work for second criteria.

I want to create a filter which will work for entire data validation that is available in the attached sheet.

If i selected the `position` from `cell C2` `Head Of Product Design` then `position` column will be shown rows with `Head Of Product Design` and then i select the `Stage Name` from `cell D2` `Profile review`. then two filter will be created 1 for C2 and other for D2 and same goes for all.

Your help will be much appreciated.

However first `onEdit` is working but second is not working i do not know why. Then i need to create filters ahead. But i am stuck on second 1.

Your help will be appreciated.

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15i1Ep46IUYLCl7odLy0YqHVJ00Z5qG_Urtwg_n5GOd4/edit#gid=1477010803)

```
function onEdit() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const value = sheet1.getRange('C2').getValue();
  const range = sheet1.getRange("A5:T");
  const filter = sheet1.getFilter();
  if (filter) {
    filter.remove();
  }
  range.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(value).build());
}

function onEdit2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const value = sheet1.getRange('D2').getValue();
  const range = sheet1.getRange("A5:T");
  const filter = sheet1.getFilter();
  if (filter) {
    filter.remove();
  }
  range.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(value).build());
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to include  onEdit2() as part of the procedure at the end of onEdit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const [c2, d2] = sheet1.getRange('C2:D2').getValues()[0];
  const range = sheet1.getRange("A5:T");
  const filter = sheet1.getFilter();
  if (filter) {
    filter.remove();
  }
  range.createFilter()
  .setColumnFilterCriteria(2, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(c2).build())
  .setColumnFilterCriteria(4, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(d2).build());
}
```

- In this modified script, your `onEdit` and `onEdit2` are merged.

### Added:

From your following new question,

> I have multiple sheets with different data but each sheet has same data validation cells and Columns where filter will apply. So your above code is being used in Sheet1, then i add same code for Sheet2 But Sheet2 code is not working. I did not changed the code name that is onEdit for both sheets

> When the Sheet1 is edited script should work for Sheet1 if Sheet2 is added scripts should work for Sheet2

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit() {
  const sheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"];
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (!sheets.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) return;
  const [c2, d2] = sheet.getRange('C2:D2').getValues()[0];
  const range = sheet.getRange("A5:T");
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter) {
    filter.remove();
  }
  range.createFilter()
  .setColumnFilterCriteria(2, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(c2).build())
  .setColumnFilterCriteria(4, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(d2).build());
}
```

- When this script is run, when the active sheet is Sheet1 and Sheet2, the script is run.
- From [OP's previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69981289/7108653), I understood that OP wants to achieve this without using the event object. So I proposed the above sample scripts.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tanaike i was not thinking it will be short code like this. Thank you. You are literally a kind man.

Comment: @ShRa Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Is it possible to use same code for different sheet, I added the same code with sheet name but its not working. @Tanaike

Comment: @ShRa About your new question of `Is it possible to use same code for different sheet, I added the same code with sheet name but its not working.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your new question from your comment. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand it. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Sure, I have multiple sheets with different data but each sheet has same data validation cells and Columns where filter will apply. So your above code is being used in Sheet1, then i add same code for Sheet2 But Sheet2 code is not working. I did not changed the code name that is `onEdit` for both sheets

Comment: @ShRa Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still imagine your new question. For example, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your current issue of your new question? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @ShRa By the way, in your new question, for example, when the Sheet1 is edited, do you want to change both Sheet1 and Sheet2? Or, when the Sheet1 is edited, do you want to change only the Sheet1? I couldn't understand your new question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: YES! you are right. When the Sheet1 is edited script should work for Sheet1 if Sheet2 is added scripts should work for Sheet2

Comment: @ShRa Thank you for replying. From your replying, I added one more sample script for your new question. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize again.